# What does it mean when a VPN add configuration window warns: “All network activity on this Mac may be filtered or monitored when using VPN?”

Tags: macos, vpn

When I rebooted the MacBook a window popped up saying that macOS wants to add configuration and:

> “All network activity on this Mac may be filtered or monitored when using VPN.”

What does this mean?

Does this mean that even if you are adding configuration for using TunnelBear VPN you get monitored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### All it means is that if you use a VPN you are not magically cloaked from being monitored by your VPN provider. Your VPN service can still monitor you.

It’s awkward wording, but all it means is that when you use a VPN you might be cloaking your real IP address from the world, but if you use a VPN all traffic must go thorough that VPN so they would know where you are and what you have looked at. It’s generic disclaimer that is meant to let you know VPNs don’t completely shield your activity; that VPN providers and ISPs when you don’t use a VPN can still monitor you.

So if you “Allow,” then the VPN will be activated. If you “Disallow,” then the VPN will not be activated.

Comment: Ah, so when I clicked the no button from "All network activity on this Mac may be filtered or monitored when using VPN." window, the VPN didn't work but when I now clicked the yes button it now works. Is there a way to reverse to go back to before configuration added? Or does that mean as long as VPN is turned on it protects from being monitored from VPN and ISPs providers?

Comment: 1. https://www.tunnelbear.com/privacy-policy
As you can see from Tunnel Bear's privacy policy they don't store users originating IP addresses. If VPN providers can still monitor then doesn't this mean that Tunnel Bear is lying?

Comment: 2. I see, then in other words of that VPN providers can still monitor, it then protects from being monitored by ISP providers? So basically if I live in Europe and use Tunnel Bear activated where it's jurisdiction is based on Canada then the European government can't force Canadian based VPN providers to produce all the records monitoring of all users that use this company then?

Comment: By the way of speaking VPN. I'm coming from a slogan

"Privacy is the foundation of free society and democracy".

Comment: Basically I have just struck from what you said from "macOS has no idea what TunnelBear's policy is." So basically when macOS notified me with the window “All network activity on this Mac may be filtered or monitored when using VPN.”, every computer machine itself knows if the browsing will still be monitored by external system or not(probably through its own OS system)?

Answer (score 0):

This message is sinister when coming from a VPN that does not track or monitor you, like Proton VPN. My Proton VPN just stopped working after I had a phone call about a taboo topic we aren't allowed to discuss in today's times. I restarted my VPN and this message came up. Proton VPN says they do not use that message. A message asking to configure your VPN should not pop up after you've been using the VPN for years. Does anyone understand that Proton VPN does not monitor customer traffic? They did not create this message. My computer was already hijacked and the powers that be delete emails as I write them when I try to warn people about things that are taboo and cannot be said.

All of our Windows and Apple and Google computers are hijacked through a back door for monitoring. Any computer using a Microsoft product is also being monitored. They are now hijacking VPN applications to make sure they can still monitor your traffic while you are using a VPN.

This is sinister. Wake up people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Let me guess You where playing about in IP Vanish's Settings? This Message  pop's up “All Network activity on the Mac to be filtered or monitored when  using VPN”.  Allow or Deny.  Any VPN Service  hide you from everyone. However they do not hide you from the VPN service themselves,  That way they will know when you are doing something that you are not meant to be doing. Its kind of scary getting that message popping up but even without that window popping up they are still watching you ok? So back to it to get the message not popping up anymore you will have to change the Active Protocol back to Open UDP. You have switched it  to any other option there so my advice is Stop playing about in the settings unless you know what you are doing… Cheers